# split int into time format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table column that has time in data type int. e.g. 732, 2215, 132, etc etc. as type int. I need to change it into time format e.g. 07:32, 22:15, 01:32 .
How can I achieve this using sql

Comment: `STUFF` and `RIGHT` spring to mind. What have you tried or searched, as I'm very confident there is a duplicate out there.

Comment: Refer (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d4512a7d597853ae9d6af66ce472166d)

Comment: [For future readers](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a94f30820e2aea4a89ddfb27db01f4bf)